# Unwanted page break after \maketitle

Tags: latex

I'm trying to remove the page break I get after the abstract section in a research paper. What could be wrong in my code?

```latex
\documentclass[preprint,pre,floats,aps,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\title{A Blockchain-Based Approach to Identity Management for the Aviation Industry}
\author{BlaBla}
\affiliation{Chair of Quantitative Business Administration}


\begin{abstract}
Some texts 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

some text

\end{document}
```

I want the introduction paragraph to be just below the abstract and not in a new page. And if anyone knows how to put a small space between the \affiliation and the /abstract that would be awesome too.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure this is not due to the formatting from the documentclass? Is it [**this one**](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1?lang=en)?

Comment: Right, I took a template but I was trying to force the title page not to break. I don't know if this is possible though?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an article to be submitted to a journal, you should adhere to the style they specify.

If you are writing just for your personal purposes, you could temporarily redefine the `\clearpage` macro:

```
\documentclass[preprint,pre,floats,aps,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\title{A Blockchain-Based Approach to Identity Management for the Aviation Industry}
\author{BlaBla}
\affiliation{Chair of Quantitative Business Administration}


\begin{abstract}
Some texts 
\end{abstract}

{
\let\clearpage\relax
\maketitle
}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

some text

\end{document}
```